# Should the URL in the "SeekToAction" Video Schema point to your own site or can it point to Vimeo, Youtube, or another video host?

Tags: seo, url, structured-data

Google recently launched "SeektoAction" as an addition to the Video Schema, however, what URL you add is not clear.

Here is their example:

```
"@type": "SeekToAction",
"target": "https://video.example.com/watch/videoID?t={seek_to_second_number}",
```

By "video.example" do they mean to add the page on your site or the video link either Vimeo, Youtube or something else?

Comment: No. That a sample URL only. You can host the video anywhere you want as long as that URL points to the video.

Comment: So I should provide a URL from my own site where the video is located?

Comment: I believe Google prefers the idea that the url links to your own site and starts the video at the specified spot. Obviously that is harder then linking to the host of the video.